# How to import contacts from  Samsung Omnia II i8000?

Tags: contacts

How can I easily import my contacts from my old phone (Samsung Omnia II). I tried to copy them from my SIM card but I lost some of the contacts' numbers. (The contact name exists but the phone number does not.)

Please advise.

Comment: As the Omnia isn't an Android device I don't know that we'll be able to help you. What are your options for exporting from it? Android, if I recall, can import CSV and VCF formats.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem withe my Ace 3, [this article](https://phones.brain-start.tech/import-contacts/how-to-import-contacts-on-samsung-galaxy-ace-3-4g/) helped me a bit. What I had to do was :

- go to "contacts"
- tap on "settings"
- "import from SIM card"
  If it did not work (like erase the numbers in your case) try erasing them from the phone and starting again, some bugs can happen. If it still does not work, you will have to ask each person to send you back there number !

Have a nice day